# How to solve this. Multiple op amps circuits in series

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

The question is. What value for R1 is correct if we want the total power amplification to become 30 dB

My calculations. 30dB is amplification of 1000 times.
Last circuit got amp of 15/1,5=10 times. 1000/10=100

We therefor need amp of first circuit to be 100 times.

10/R1=100

R1=0.1kohm

We could tick in 100 ohm but according to solutions manual the correct answer is 3.2kohm and I do not understand why.

Comment: "30dB is amplification of 1000 times". No, it isn't. Take another look into the use of decibels for voltage gain.

Comment: "30dB is amplification of 1000 times". Yes it is, for power amplification. But without knowing source and load impedances, the question is unanswerable in current form. Informally, solve it by assuming they don't mean power gain = 30dB, but voltage gain = 30dB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

30 dB amplification as a voltage ratio is \$10^{30/20}\$ = 31.62.

Given that the 2nd stage has a gain of 10 the first stage has a gain of 3.16 hence, R1 approximately equals 3.162 kohm.

> 30dB is amplification of 1000 times

30 dB is a power ratio of 1000 and a voltage ratio of \$\sqrt{1000}\$

Comment: I forgot to mention but it was 30dB power amplification and not voltage

Comment: 30 dB of power amplification is still an equivalent voltage amplification (assuming same value input and output resistances) of 31.62. Do the math.

Comment: Second circuit got amp of 10 times. 20*log(10)=20dB voltage amplification. First circuit must have 10dB amp which is 3.16 times. I get the correct answer when I calculate for voltage gain but not for power

Comment: Apart from anything else, unless you show an output load resistor there is no power amplification because the load is open circuit and therefore takes zero power.

Comment: Okay but our textbook states that:

power gain = 10^(power gain (dB)/10)
and
voltage gain = 10^(power gain (dB)/20)

so you mean that because there is no load attached I should calculate as voltage gain despite that the text tell me that the power amplification is 30dB?

Comment: That is correct so, either your question is badly phrased when it refers to power gain (because there can be none without an output load) or you omitted the load resistor from where you copied the question. Maybe you need to photograph the original question and post it.

Comment: The picture is all I got. The question is written in swedish so I believe there is no good reason to post it here so I did a somewhat rough translation but missed out on the power part but as concluded it did not matter.

Comment: Well, if you translated it correctly and the recognized correct answer is 3.2 kohm then the words in the question are incorrectly phrased for that answer.

Comment: A better translation would be:

The two cascaded amplifiers below shall give a power amplification of 30 dB. What resistance must you choose for R1 for this to become true?

That is the best translation and most accurate I could do

Comment: It still contradicts the answer - power amplification literally means watts out divided by watts in. Clearly there can be watts in because of R1 hence you apply an input voltage and current is taken and power in = volts_in x current_in. But, with no load resistor there can be no output current and therefore no power out. Having said all that, it's a common mistake to make and most electrical engineers would look at the question, see the shortfall and assume that an attempt at an answer based on voltage amplification can be made.

Comment: Okay, this question was from last years exams. I am studying robotics engineering and the teacher probably wanted the students to think that way then. I do not know. But at least I know now how to get the correct answer. The textbook would have solved that question the way I did but I remember that the teacher said the textbook was too nice to the students. Maybe it is something like that because this one was made by the teacher

Answer (score 1):

You mixed up power and voltage gains. As per the question Power amplification is:

$$ 10 log (P_o/P_i) = 30 dB $$
Since P is proportional to \$ V^2 \$  , we can also write:
$$ 10 log (V_o^2/V_i^2) = 30 dB$$
Or
$$ 20 log (V_o/V_i) = 30 dB$$
$$ i.e., log (V_o/V_i) = 1.5 dB$$
Therefore the corresponding voltage amplification is:
$$ (V_o/V_i) = 10^{1.5} = 31.62$$

Comment: Decibels, decibels or dB and not DB nor Db nor db or anything with an "s" on the end to pluralize it. The d is for deci and it is used lower case.

Comment: oh yea......correct. I was thinking something looks weird in the equations... got it :D